# Alignment of 3 horizontal images at the footer in Android

Tags: android, html, css

I'm working on Android. I want to align 3 Images at the footer Horizontally.
Below is my code. thank you in advance

```
      <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/footer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="#ccc"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_padding="-30dp">

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgView6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgView6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgView6"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So? What others should do now?

Comment: do something with your `imageViews` just like for first image add `android:alignParentLeft="true"`, for center image `android:layouttoLeftof="@id/fisrt_image"` and for last image add this `android:layouttoRightof="@id/second_image"`. And please change the ids of images to different names as you have set same names for all three images.

Comment: @ Milan Maharajan, i'm not able to align it horizontal

Comment: @ user3294039, thank you, will apply the same

Comment: @ anirudha, you don't do anything, and I don't think so that you are so wise to ask such questions to others. If you dont know the answer atleast don't comment

Comment: @ user3294039, after applying rightof and leftof, only two images are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want all 3 image views to be of equal size? I would use a linear layout with the orientation to be horizontal and each image view yo have a weight of 1